# Solving the integral equation $x(t)=e^{-t}+2\int_0^t \sin(t-u) \, x(u)~du$

Tags: integration

How do you solve this integral equation?

$$x(t)=e^{-t}+2\int_0^t \sin(t-u) \, x(u) \, du$$

I have tried using integration by parts, as well as substitution, but ran into dead ends for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach involving the one-sided Laplace Transform. It is ideal to use here since $\int_0^t \sin(t-u)x(u)~du$ is just $\sin(t)\ast x(t)$, where $*$ represents convolution. In general, one would use the following approach to solve these kinds of problems:

1. Take the Laplace Transform on both sides of the integral equation.
2. Solve for $X(s)$, where $X(s):=\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}$
3. Take the Inverse Laplace Transform of $X(s)$ to recover $x(t)$.

---

Let's first do step 1. Taking the Laplace transform on both sides, we obtain:
$$\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{e^{-t}\}+2\mathcal{L}\left\{\sin(t)\ast x(t)\right\}$$
Now recall that $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\ast g(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\cdot \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}$. Therefore:
$$\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{e^{-t}\}+2\mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\}\cdot \mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}$$
All of these are basic Laplace transforms which you can find on a [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), hence:
$$X(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}+2\cdot \frac{1}{s^2+1}\cdot X(s)$$

---

Step 2 is just elementary algebra, which it should give:
$$\begin{align}X(s)&=\frac{s^2+1}{(s^2-1)(s+1)}\\&=\frac{s}{s^2-1}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2} \end{align}$$
Where on the last step, I have rewritten the expression just for convenience.

---

Now for step 3, we need to take the inverse Laplace Transform of both sides. Hence, by the linearity of the inverse Laplace Transform, we have:
$$x(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{s}{s^2-1}\right\}-\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{(s+1)^2}\right\}$$
These should be easy to find using a [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), and you will have solved your integral equation.

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Let us take two derivatives of $x(t)$:

$$
\dot{x} = -e^{-t} + 2 \int\limits_0^t \cos (t - u) x(u) \; du \\[7pt]
\ddot{x} = e^{-t} - 2 \int\limits_0^t \sin (t-u) x(u) \; du  + 2 x(t) = x + 2e^{-t}
$$

Therefore, we have

$$
\ddot{x} - x = 2e^{-t},
$$

which is an ode of second order.

PS. Another approach would be to use one-sided Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you so much!

How would the Laplace transform work?

Comment: $$\mathcal{L} [e^{-t}] (p) = \frac{1}{1+p}, \quad \mathcal{L} [\sin t] = \frac{1}{p^2+1}$$

Note that integral is the convolution of $\sin(t)$ and $x(t)$. Via convolution theorem, $\mathcal{L}[f * g] = \mathcal{L}[f] \, \mathcal{L}[g]$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a bit confused. Why was the second derivative taken?

Comment: In order to obtain a differential equation for $x(t)$.

Comment: So the answer would be an ode?

Comment: No, but this ode is easy to solve. An arbitrary solution to it is $$x(t) = -t e^{-t} + c_1 e^t + c^2 e^{-t}.$$

Comment: When doing this approach, one must also state the initial conditions $x(0)=1$ and $\dot{x}(0)=-1$, otherwise the integral equation doesn't satisfy for general $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: hmm I think I get it. Thank you!